# JSON-RPC PHP class not found error

Tags: php, class, json-rpc

I am using this php wrapper for multichain's json rpc api: https://github.com/Kunstmaan/libphp-multichain in a php file.

I'm not sure how I should adjust my code and I'm reluctant to adjust the libraries so I wanted to check this understanding:

```
<?php
   require_once 'libphp-multichain/src/be/kunstmaan/multichain/MultichainClient.php';
   require_once 'libphp-multichain/src/be/kunstmaan/multichain/MultichainHelper.php';
   $client = new MultichainClient("http://107.170.46.124:port",{usr},{pwd});
   print_r($client);
```

The error I see in apache error log is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MultichainClient' not found in /var/www/html/new.php on line 5

Previously I had the wrong question on here which was referring to a php error treating MultichainClient as a function

Comment: You forgot `new` so `$client = new MultichainClient(...);`

Answer (score 3):

this is not a function, you're trying to declare an instance of a `new` class object. so add the `new` keyword

```
$client = new MultichainClient("multichainrpc","password","host","port",3);
```